# asp.net validation expression military time with leading zeros

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I am using this expression `^(([0-9])|([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):(([0-9])|([0-5][0-9]))$` which works great for validating military time with colons... how do I modify so that it REQUIRES leading zeros for times under 10?

Answer (score 1):

Just drop the first alternation:

```
^(([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):(([0-9])|([0-5][0-9]))$
```

It is the one that allows for single digit hours.

Answer (score 1):

Git rid of `([0-9])|` toward the start of the expression.  That allows only one digit.  The stuff after | requires two digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):(([0-5][0-9]))$
```

This version will require both the hours AND the minutes to be 2 digits.